# GoogleDrive: Programmatically declare a file to be available offline

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to programmatically set a google-drive-file as offline available? I can't find a way in the API and always have to use a google-frontend (on web or android) to do so.

If there is a way, please sketch out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file update parameters do not include the offline access option https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

There's an accesstype option for the authorization to be set to offline, but I do not think it has to do anything with the file access.

Comment: Yes, this is what I found out too. So, currently, the answer to my question is no.